# C# application that process cgi

Tags: c#, cgi

I had a PLC that is trying to access a cgi script. ie formdata.cgi. At the same time it will also pass over 2 arguments for processing.
How do i create the formdata.cgi so that i can read and process the arguments all within c# winform environment?
Please point me in a right direction as google searching is providing me with too many confusing ways and results.

Comment: Sorry, PLC is "Programmable Logic Controller"?

Comment: @Fabioln Yes PLC refer to programmable logic controller.

Comment: Maybe this will help you...: "C# application to make connection and read/write From PLC" (https://support.industry.siemens.com/tf//ww/en/posts/c-application-to-make-connection-and-read-write-from-plc/180841?page=0&pageSize=10)

Comment: Mesta Automation - 
A blog about WPF, C# and PCL software development - 
https://www.mesta-automation.com/siemens-s7-plc-c-s7-net-plc-driver/

Comment: PLC Communication Using .Net (https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/asmabegam/plc-communication-using-net/)

Comment: @FabioIn thanks for the suggestion. However there is already a web service in the library of the PLC. Hence the protocol suggested may not work. I did see some option in OPC UA in the PLC and could explore that area a little more. Meanwhile i will read whatever the string i get from the PLC and dissect the information i need.

Comment: Yes, is very specific question, maybe in another Fórum.